# Access python dict value in yaml with tags

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

Is it possible to load the value from a python dict in yaml?

I can access variable by using:

```
!!python/name:mymodule.myfile.myvar
```

but this give the whole dict.

Trying to use dict get method like so:

```
test: &TEST !!python/object/apply:mymod.myfile.mydict.get ['mykey']
```

give me the following error:

> yaml.constructor.ConstructorError: while constructing a Python object cannot find module 'mymod.myfile.mydict' (No module named 'mymod.myfile.mydict'; 'mymod.myfile' is not a package)

I'm trying to do that because I have bunch of yaml files which define my project settings, one is for path directory, and I need to load it into some other yaml files and it looks like you cant load yaml variable from another yaml.

EDIT:

I have found one solution, creating my own function who return the values in dict and calling it like so:

```
test: &TEST !!python/object/apply:mymod.myfile.get_dict_value ['mykey']
```

Comment: Please clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no mechanism in YAML to refer to one document from another YAML document.

You'll have to do that by interpreting information in the document **in the program** that loads the initial YAML document. Whether you do that by explicit logic, or by using some tag doesn't make a practical difference.

Please be aware that it is unsafe to allow interpreting tags of the form ``` !!python/name:.....`` (via yaml=YAML(typ='unsafe') ``` in ruamel.yaml, or `load()` in PyYAML), and is never really necessary.

Comment: if i write explicit logic into python to modify my settings, my settings are setup in two different places and this looks bad for readability, i would prefer to have everything into yaml